# Where can I find speed and thrust data for airplanes during the approach?

Tags: fuel, airspeed

While trying to gather information on fuel consumption during the approach I have found this equation :

$$f=C_{f1}\cdot (1+V_{TAS}/C_{f2})\cdot T$$  ([on this FAA paper](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/research/models/sage/media/FAA-EE-2005-01_SAGE-Technical-Manual.pdf))

- $f$ is the fuel flow
- $T$ is the thrust acting parallel to the aircraft velocity vector
- $C_{f1}$ and $C_{f2}$ are the first and second thrust-specific fuel consumption coefficient
- $V_{TAS}$ is the true air speed

From what I have understood Cf1 and Cf2 are constant and their values can be found (all the documents regarding these issues are 100 pages papers so I have not read everything yet).

I would like to plot the fuel flow for different airspeeds and thrusts. What are the typical values during the approach ?
I would like to have these data for several flights during the last 20 or 25 minutes of the flight.

What I am looking for is exactly what flightaware.com provides except that they use ground speed ([an exemple here](https://fr.flightaware.com/live/flight/AFR7627/history/20170211/1105Z/LFBD/LFPG/tracklog)). How can I convert to TAS ? 
Also they don't provide anything on thrust. Do you know where I can find thrust data ?

Comment: For what it may be worth, a 747-200 with Pratt & Whitney JT9 engines at flaps 30 degrees, gear down, stabilized on a 3 degree glideslope will show a fuel flow of approximately 5,000 lbs/hr for each engine.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is collected, though not published, in airlines' Flight Data Monitoring (FDM).
Airlines collect a load of parameters for training and statistical purposes. If you can contact an airline, tell them what you're doing and make it sound like you could improve fuel economy, there's a good chance you can get some of the data.
Another place to seek would be aircraft manufacturers like Boeing or Airbus.